# On a system with ARM A9 processor, L2CACHE, SRAM. is it possible to have a C program to get the following performance data

Tags: c, embedded, arm

On a system with ARM A9 processor, L2CACHE, SRAM. is it possible to have a C program to get the following performance data:

1. Avg. SRAM data Fetch delay.
2. Avg. Instruction Fetch delay.

Comment: Why don't you just trust the processor datasheet ?

Comment: @Claudio - We need a comparison between system which has ITCM/DTCM Vs one which runs the instructions from SRAM. Are all these combinations covered in the data sheet?

Answer (score 1):

If you have hardware targets to run and measure on, you could create test code that can get cycle counts between different points of its execution, using Cortex-A9 PMU (ref [A9 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388i/DDI0388I_cortex_a9_r4p1_trm.pdf) chapter 11). Your test code would need to initialize and read from PMU registers. Then, PMU will measure cycle count and give other interesting data e.g. number of cache misses. That much is doable with software.

However, that resulting performance data may not be as low-level as you may want.

Consider a loop over a block of NOP instructions, with loop counter in a register. L1 instruction cache would fill on the first iteration. PMU can give you a measurement of instruction cycles and total time. That measurement would relate to L1 instruction fetch delay (unless you use a *really big* block, in which case you might shed light on L2).

Similarly you could construct test code whose execution time will also include effect of data fetch delay.

There is [ARM example code](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4237.html) which shows how PMU can be used.

You may find [processor internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106297/is-arm-cortex-a8-pipeline-13-stage-or-14-stage?rq=1) to be complicated. If L2 is your primary interest, the controller e.g. [L2C-310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509630/how-to-read-l2-cache-hit-miss-rate-in-android-arm?rq=1) may have its own event counters, although I haven't used such.